# gulp - Beep when done

Tags: javascript, gulp, response, feedback, beep

I want to make voice control/feedback/response for my build in **gulp**. I wrote something like this below, but it is not working.
Does anybody know how to fix it? :)

It throws [this error](http://prntscr.com/6lxpzu).

```
// Compile Sass, autoprefix properties, generate CSS.
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return sass('src/sass/style.scss', {style: 'compressed'})
    .pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(rename('style.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/css/'))
    .pipe(gutil.beep()) // beep when build is done
})
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove `.pipe(gutil.beep())`?

Comment: The build works, but I want 'beep' after the build will done.

Comment: What version of `gulp-util` do you have?  According to [this](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-util/issues/35), `beep()` was removed at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@lsowen pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29300726/gulp-beep-when-done#comment46797532_29300726), *gulp-util* does not have the `beep` function anymore, so you should

```
npm install --save-dev beepbeep
```

And do something like:

```
var beep = require('beepbeep');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return sass('src/sass/style.scss', { style: 'compressed' })
    .pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(rename('style.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/css/'))
      .on('end', function () { beep(); });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Or just use

```
console.log('\x07');
```

Answer (score 4):

As of now, `gulp-util` has the `beep` method.  So you can add this to the end of your gulp workflow >> `.on('end', function () { gutil.beep(); });`